# Wireplumber on Debian 12 do not auto-switch a2dp to HSP/HFS on Skype call start

Tags: debian, audio, bluetooth, skype

I have Debian 12 OS and use Bluetooth headphones, but every time I make a Skype call, I need to switch from Headset to Handsfree in Gnome sound settings manually. I read some articles about Wireplumber there is an auto-switch function enabled by default, but in my case, it is not true.

The Wireplumber version is 0.4.13. Is it possible to fix this?

I tried to reinstall Pipewire and Wireplumber, but the same problem still exists.